# Error accessing web service in a WinForm project

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, namespaces, service-reference

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to consume a web service I wrote with a windows application. The Web service appears to work fine normally and I don't get any errors, but as soon as I add it as a Service Reference in my WinForms application I get the error:

```
Error   1   The type name 'ServiceReference1' does not exist in the type 'CosmicInterface.CosmicInterface'
```

Now, I have a feeling it has to do with namespaces but just can't figure out where. Here's a snippet of my web services code:

```
namespace CosmicSvc
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.website.com")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class cosmic : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod()]
        public string etc....
```

The service file is named 'cosmic.asmx' which I'm not sure plays into it at all.

And here's what little code is in my windows application named 'CosmicInterface'. All I've done is said 'new project' and then added the service reference and tried to run. That's when I get the errors. So there's not a lot of code. I added the service reference under several names, finally leaving it at the default 'ServiceRefrence1'.

```
namespace CosmicInterface
{
    public partial class CosmicInterface : Form
    {
        public CosmicInterface()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u try this in CosmicInterface,
using ServiceReference1;

Comment: Can you clarify exactly when you're getting the error because the error seems to indicate that you are actually trying to call your web service from your winform app; if that's the case, let's see how you're trying to call it. But, the way you've listed the error it looks like a compile time error. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out. Turns out I had my namespace and class named the same. Changed the class and it worked 
fine.

```
namespace CosmicInterface
{
        public partial class InterfaceForm : Form // <- I had to change this name to something different...
        {
            public InterfaceForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It should not really helpful question/answer. Just delete initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class name of the WCF client application to be different from the namespace
Change the namespace encapsulating the WCF client application class (resulting the class being in a different namespace than the reference).